# I am getting chat window in the stack overflow site i think this not belongs to stack overflow any idea?

Tags: discussion

While accessing the stack overflow site i am getting the below chat popup and the below message need expert assistance like popup can and also some one is chat to  me

is it belongs to stack overflow?

Anybody know about that why it is coming?

Thanks in advance!!!

[image: Image : Reference]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a malicious activity. 
you need to google following keywords:

1. Gregorian Calendar
2. Today's date

If you are still not able to find the answer see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert)

Comment: ohh !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

April Fools' Day

> April Fools' Day is celebrated in many countries on April 1 every
>   year. Sometimes referred to as All Fools' Day, April 1 is not a
>   national holiday, but is widely recognized and celebrated as a day
>   when people play practical jokes and hoaxes on each other.

Comment: Incidentally, also celebrated as the professional holiday of all security-oblivious programmers and developers...

Comment: http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/T2WQSXeYUeMQ :))